# How to convert data from SQL Server format to a number format in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I'm receiving a file that is exported to Excel via SQL Server. The cells in the file have the green error checking notification and all cells on the sheet appear to be formatted as GENERAL. However the error checking notification says that the cells are formatted as TEXT or have a leading apostrophe but when you actually click inside the cell to edit there is no leading apostrophe and technically the sheet is formatted as GENERAL.

If I manually highlight my range and click on the error checking dropdown options to fix the problem and select convert to number, my code runs perfectly. I tried recording a macro to see the code that would be written for the error checking conversion to number format but it didn't record anything while it converted to number.

Is there VBA code that uses the error checking convert to number function instead of doing it manually by selecting that option through the dropdown?

Comment: Would it be possible to simply multiply each cell by 1? I've seen this done to convert text to numbers before, but I haven't dabbled in SQL, so I really have no idea

Comment: @seadoggie01 This would work actually. I could just go down the range of the sheet and do that calculation. I just wonder if there is actual code that could change a range quicker than having to run through the whole sheet and change every individual cell.

Comment: There is! just a moment...

Answer (score 0):

Copy a cell that has a value of one and paste it (while multiplying) to the range of cells you wish to change. This will not affect any other cells, like "real text".

```
'Copy the cell with value of 1 (mine was on a different sheet
Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1").Copy
'Paste skipping blanks and multiplying by 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
    SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```